# Encryption Initialization Vector Failed

Tags: encryption, aes, pascal, initialization-vector

I am facing a strange problem, i am using aes encryption with cfb mode. It is going good, I had tested the encryption with fixed IV. But when i use a random IV the problem shows up. I am going in detail.

```
function Random16DigitsString: AnsiString;
var
  i: Integer; c0: byte;
begin
  Randomize;
  c0:=ord('0');
  SetLength(Result, 16);
  Result[1] := char(c0+Random(9)+1);
  for i:=2 to 16 do Result[i] := char(c0+Random(10));
end;
```

The sample output of the above code is 8229343736510872

When i use this function in encryption phase its ok, but when i decrypt the file using the same key then the output is garbage. But when i hard code this key in encryption phase then the decryption successfully goes.

What i am missing. I am going with simple random number generator.

Comment: 1) Why are you using an `AnsiString`, not an `array[0..15] of byte`? 2) `Random` sucks, it's certainly inappropriate for any crypto use. 3) You should generate all possible bytes, not just ASCII digits 4) You need to use the same IV for decryption that you used for encryption. Prepending the IV to the ciphertext is standard practice.

Comment: I am using AnsiString to store the IV, I am unable to understand why the same key when generated randomly not worked, but when the same key is hard coded in the string it worked.

Comment: i had checked the value of IV is same in encryption and decryption phase (using random generated code) and with (hard coded IV value). Then why this problem, i am really confused

Comment: Then post enough code to reproduce your problem. While the code you posted *sucks* it's not responsible for your immediate problem.

Comment: I removed the [tag:c] tag as this question appears to relate to [tag:pascal] only.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Firstly thank you for pointing AnsiString issue. But it was not in the IV Section but instead it was in the Context. Any way thank you. I don't know how to accept your answer in comment section. sorry for it, I am new to stackoverflow. Thank You.

Comment: @Rahul Post your own answer describing what was wrong, and how you fixed it. Then accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using AnsiString to store the Key for the Context. This was the real problem because in pascal AnsiString is not single byte. As @CodeInChaos focused on AnsiString, I checked it and found it. So i had replaced the

```
Key: AnsiString
```

To

```
Key : Array [0..32] of Char;
```

and it successfully worked.

Thank you @CodeInChaos.